# How to append text to a TextView after setText()?

Tags: java, android, textview, buttonclick

This is `MainActivity` of my calculator application in which I am trying to first `setText()` and then append to the `TextView main`.

My problem is that `append()` does work but it only appends once after I call the `setText()` method. I want it to append text multiple times.

How do I do that?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator_screen);

        TextView main = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maintextView);
        main.setText("0.");

        Button btnSeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnseven);
        btnSeven.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       switch(view.getId()) {
           case R.id.btnseven:
               TextView main = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maintextView);
               main.setText("");
               main.append("7");
               break;
           default :
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you reset the text on your TextView by doing:

```
main.setText("");
```

before doing the append action. Here is what your code should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView mMain;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator_screen);

        mMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maintextView);
        mMain.setText("0");

        Button btnSeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnseven);
        btnSeven.setOnClickListener(this);
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String mainText = mMain.getText().toString();
        try {
            // By parsing the text as a number, you make sure you handle the cases where the user added input like "0." too, so you don't have to handle each and every case with Strings and with if-else statements.
            double actualNumber = Double.parseDouble(mainText);
            if (actualNumber == 0) {
                mMain.setText("");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Something went wrong while parsing. Usually happens because the EditText contains other characters the digits or "."
        }

        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnseven:
                mMain.append("7");
                break; 
            default : 
                break; 
        } 
    } 
}
```